# How to block referrers that come from specific domain TLD?

Tags: nginx, spam

Recently I'm getting many hits to my website coming from spam referrers using different domain names and they're all `.ru` domains. I'm using Nginx on my server.

Currently I'm using the below code to block popular spam referrers such us Semalt but I won't be able to insert every `.ru` domain, they always come up with new ones.

```
if ($http_referer ~ "7makemoneyonline\.com|semalt\.com|Get-Free-Traffic-Now\.com) { 
       return 403;
}
```

My question is: how to block all requests that referred from any `.ru` domain name without interfering with other domain names that contain `ru` letters in their names, for example: *d**ru**gs.com*?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression matching domain names should be anchored to the end of the line by using the `$` token. For example, to match `www.example.org`, `example.com` and `.net` you would use:

```
if ($http_referer ~* (www\.example\.org|example\.com|\.net)$ ) { ... }
```

That is a number of candidates, separated by `|` and enclosed in parentheses. The final `$` anchors it to the end of the line.